# Is column 0 in a SQLite database taken up by the ROWID?

Tags: android, sqlite

Currently, I have a database where I am using random longs as my IDs, so I don't need an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. Can I use my own IDs in column 0, or is column 0 automatically taken up by the implicit ROWID regardless?

Comment: Seems to me like something of this importance should be in the developer docs. Have you read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tables have a `rowid`.
It is not a normal column but used as the key of the table's B-tree structure.

If you declare a column as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, that column is used as the `rowid` and is not actually stored in the table's data section.

If your primary key is an integer, you should declare it as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` to make storage and lookups more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use you own ID's. ROW ID can be used separately (SQLITE)